# Mensagem de medalha concedida não traduzido

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Como podem repara não está traduzido o texto na mensagem de medalha concedida:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

"Você ganhou a medalha... em..."